# Choice of trivializations in the definition of a vector bundle

Tags: vector-bundles

In the definition of vector bundle $E$ it is required that at every point $p$ there exists a local diffeomorphism $\phi_p$ from an open neighbourhood of p $U_p$ to $U_p \times V$. If we now take any linear invertible function $A :V \rightarrow V$, we can define $\phi'_p =  A \circ\phi_p$ (with $A$ just acting on the fiber I hope the notation is clear) which should still be a diffeomorphism. Is $\phi'_p$ still an admissible diffeomorphism? Do we change something important considering in the definition $\phi'_p$ instead of $\phi_p$? Of course the structure functions would change but is the vector bundle itself changing? Told another way, does the choice of the local diffeomorphisms have an impact on the properties of the vector bundle?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you don't change the isomorphic class of your vector bundle. If $p:P\rightarrow M$ is a vector bundle, $(U_i,\phi_i)$ is a trivialization, $\phi:p^{-1}(U_i)\rightarrow U_i\times V$, $\phi_i\circ {\phi_j}^{-1}(x,y)=(x,g_{ij}(y)$ is a $1$-cocycle: $g_{ij}g_{jk}=g_{ik}$. The isomorphic class of the vector bundle is defined by this cocycle. if you define $\psi_i=(Id,A_i)\circ\phi_i$ you modify the 1-cocycle by a boundary and the resulting bundle is isomorphic to the first one. This is explained in every introductory book on the subject.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So if I understood correctly I am changing the vector bundle, but getting to an isomorphic one. I have an other question. What you wrote is indeed called in the textbooks I saw "cocycle condition", even if the definition of vector bundles I find are not directly related to homology or cohomology theories. Your answer makes me think nevertheless that there is a cohomolody theory underlying the structure functions. And there is a relation between this cohomology theory and the class of isomorphism of vector bundles. Is it so?

Comment: Certainly, it is non commutative cohomology, one cocycles represens bundles and two cocycles gerbes, nobody really knows exactly what happens for n>2.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any reference for this and a more precise one for the fact that is cited in elementary books?... But I do not think I need to understand non commutative cohomology in order to understand such a basic proprierty of vector bundles. Is there an other way to grasp, at least intuitively, this elementary fact?

Comment: I have been looking around but cannot find a place where this point is made clear. Any reference?